# Android: How to make EditText digital input string into int?

Tags: java, android

I want to enter a figure which can be sent out with
By: `usbService.write ()`;

`C1` is the effect I want, but would like to form `C2` by `EditText` achieve the same effect

Because the need to use `byte []`, so it is necessary do the conversion action
Current input (128), a single number can reach my desired effect.

But I need a continuous instruction such as: (128 135)
`int i = Integer.parseInt (data);` will collapse.

By `EditText` want to enter a series of numbers into the instruction `byte []` into
Achieve the same effect the following

```
byte p1 = (byte) 128
byte p2 = (byte) 135

byte [] c1 = new byte [128];
c1 [0] = p1;
c1 [1] = p2;
usbService.write (c1);

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    String data = editText.getText().toString();

    int i=Integer.parseInt(data);
    byte [] C2= ByteBuffer.allocate(1024).putInt(i).array();


    display.append(data);
    usbService.write(C2);
}
```

Comment: So you want to restrict user to enter only numbers right?

Comment: Yes, I will only use the numbers
The current problem is that I also entered into two sets of numbers in EditText (128 135) will collapse
Because I need to enter multiple sets of numbers into a byte []

Comment: so for multiple sets of number cant you have multiple `editText` box?

Comment: Since more than five groups might use a combination of numbers, it is desirable to use only a `editText`,because space is also required to use other functions.

Comment: please check my modified answer, with that implemention user can enter multiple set of numbers with space in between each set of number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the input type of your `editText` to number something like below:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number|text"/>
```

And while fetching the numbers you can fetch them and split them using space something like below:

```
String data = editText.getText().toString();
String[] numberStrings = data.split(" ");
int[] numberArray = new int[numberStrings.length];
for (int i = 0; i < numberStrings.length; i++){
    numberArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberStrings[i].trim());
}
```

this way you will have all the numbers in that `numberArray`. Hope it helps.

Comment: int[] `numberArray`
Reports any array fields or variables whose contents are read but not written, or written but not read. Such mismatched reads and writes are pointless, and probably indicate dead,incomplete or erroneous code.
@@

Comment: i didn't get what you said, but anyway sorry that it was not what you expected.

Comment: Although the problem has not yet resolved, but still very grateful for your help.

Comment: I am grateful with your help, and later on the basis of your way to do modifications, finally got the desired result

Comment: That is really great! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

```
  String data=editText.getText().toString();
  String[] dataArray=data.split(" ");
  int l=dataArray.length;
  int[] intArray=new int[l];
  byte [] byteArray=new byte[l];


  for (int k=0;k<l;k++){
       intArray[k]=Integer.parseInt(dataArray[k]);
       byteArray[k]=(byte)intArray[k];
       }
  usbService.write(byteArray);
```

The problem is that before the last I do not know how to convert a byte [].Beginner has a long road to learn